# Replacing bad characters of a String with bad characters

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I just wondered what's the easiest way to replace a string characters that must be replaced subsequently.

For example:

```
var str = "[Hello World]";
//enclose all occurences of [ and ] with brackets[] 
str = str.Replace("[","[[]").Replace("]","[]]");
```

- The desired result: `[[]Hello World[]]`
- The actual result: `[[[]]Hello World[]]`

The reason is obviously the second replace on the already modified string.

So how to replace all occurences of "bad" characters with characters that contain "bad" characters?

---

A quick measurement of all approaches revealed that the [StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264450/284240) is the most efficient way.

190kb file (all in  milliseconds)

> ```
>   regexTime           40.5065  
>   replaceTime         20.8891  
>   stringBuilderTime    6.9776
> ```

7MB file

> ```
>   regexTime           1209.3529           
>   replaceTime          403.3985   
>   stringBuilderTime    175.2583
> ```

By the way, the direct `StringBuilder` approach from *John*  was twice as fast as the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) approach from *Sehe*.

I've made an extension out of it:

```
public static String EncloseChars(this string input, char[] charsToEnclose, String leftSide, String rightSide) {
    if (charsToEnclose == null || leftSide == null || rightSide == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid arguments for EncloseChars", charsToEnclose == null ? "charsToEnclose" : leftSide == null ? "leftSide" : "rightSide");
    Array.Sort(charsToEnclose);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in input) {
        if (Array.BinarySearch(charsToEnclose, c) > -1)
            sb.Append(leftSide).Append(c).Append(rightSide);
        else 
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

"[Hello World]".EncloseChars(new char[]{'[', ']'},"[","]");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very *uncool* way to do it. But it has the advantage of being pretty close to foolproof, I think, and not using regex (in case you'd rather not use regex).

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in str.ToCharArray()) {
    if (c == '[' || c == ']') {
        sb.Append('[' + c + ']');
    }
    else {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. Often the uncool way is the best/fastest. No problem when hidden in an extension method ;)

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```cs
str = str.Replace("[", "$1[$2")
         .Replace("]", "$1]$2")
         .Replace("$1", "[")
         .Replace("$2", "]");
```

Comment: Nice idea, using monitor values as intermediaries.

Comment: But you should check if the string not already contains these monitor values, or the same happens again. Example: `Hello [$1]`

Comment: The edit to replace the monitor values + the actual characters before replacing the actual character values may fix Oliver's problem (albeit in a walls-and-ladders kind of way), but at the expense of readability, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What about this elegant regular expression approach:

```
Regex.Replace("[Hello World]", @"[\[\]]", "[$0]");
```

---

Unit test it?

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestThat()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(@"[[]Hello World[]]", Regex.Replace("[Hello World]", @"[\[\]]", "[$0]"));
}
```

Test passed

---

Edit @JohnMcGrant

Here is a slightly less inefficient version of your code, which has, by the way, exactly the same behaviour as the above regex:

```
string result = input.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, c) =>
    -1 != "[]".IndexOf(c) ? a.AppendFormat("[{0}]", c) : a.Append(c)).ToString();
```

Comment: Probably safe to assume this wouldn't happen, but what if the bracketed text could legitimately contain brackets, maybe escaped in some way. Wouldn't that break the regex?

Comment: @JohnMGant: No, because that means the requirements changed. What if the question was different? Would that break the answer? Nope.

Comment: Added alternative approach based on @JohnMGant's version. I think the regex is still the best approach :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
char[] replacedChars = str.SelectMany(ch => 
                                     (ch == '[' ? new char[] {'[', '[', ']'} :
                                     (ch == ']' ? new char[] {'[', ']', ']'} : 
                                     new char[] {ch}))).ToArray();
string replaced = new string(replacedChars);
```

Note that this avoids the multiple loops issue but creates at least as many arrays as there are characters in the input string so it might not be optimal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Char singleCharacter in str)
    {
        result.Append(singleCharacter.Equals('[') ? "[[]" : singleCharacter.Equals(']') ? "[]]" : singleCharacter.ToString());
    }

    str = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, so I made a helper function to do just that

```
    protected string ReplaceUsingDictionary(string subject, Dictionary<string,string> pairs)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(subject);

        sb.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}");

        int i=0;
        foreach (string key in pairs.Keys.ToArray())
        {
            sb.Replace(
                key.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}"), 
                "{" + i + "}"
            );

            i++;
        }

        return string.Format(sb.ToString(), pairs.Values.ToArray());
    }

// usage
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
replacements["["] = "[[]";
replacements["]"] = "[]]";

string mystr = ReplaceWithDictionary("[HelloWorld]", replacements); // returns [[]HelloWorld[]]
```