# How do I write a regex to find and replace in C# (Unicode/Localization)

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write a regex to find and replace मेरा नाम (राम) है to मेरा नाम (राम) हो in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856478/how-do-i-write-a-regex-to-find-and-replace-to)

Before closing this question read it once, because I have been researching to develop an open source translator for the past 5 hours and I got stuck. Its about localization and Unicode. Its not that easy. I had to write it in Devanagari because that's what I am doing: http://code.google.com/p/nepaliwikipediatranslator

I have two sentences.

```
1) मेरा नाम राम है and   2) मेरा नाम हरी है
```

Which means My name is Ram and My name is Hari

I want to find and replace the auxiliary verb है to हो

```
input 1: 
मेरा नाम राम है 
output1:
मेरा नाम राम हो 

input 2: 
उसका नाम हरी है  
output2:
उसका नाम हरी हो
```

I have this function

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Myclass{
   public static string ReplaceIt(string sentence,string a,string b){
       Regex aRegex = new Regex(a);
       translatedString = aRegex.Replace(sentence, b);
    }
}
```

what would be my regular expression for example:

```
Myclass.ReplaceIt("मेरा नाम राम है","(\w) है","$1 हो");
```

The above code works works but the code below does not when I want to include the word "Name"(नाम) in the parameter as:

```
Myclass.ReplaceIt("मेरा नाम राम है","नाम (\w) है","नाम $1 हो");
```

The last one does not work:
I want to include नाम in the parameters to make it specific.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `@"(\w) छ","$1 हो"` instead?

Comment: That would replace every possible छ with हो That replaces every occurence of छ to हो।

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be a similar issue i've had recently with `String.Replace`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264262/replacing-bad-characters-of-a-string-with-bad-characters I may be wrong.

Comment: @Rajesh: I meant, shouldn't you use the `@`-sign to allow proper escaping?

Comment: Don't know : 
string sentence = "मेरा नाम राम है", a = "[नाम ](\w) है", b = "$1 हो"
Tried  : 
<code>Myclass.ReplaceIt(sentence,a,b) </code>

and it gives another interesting result, it eats up the vowel from the next word and gives the result: मेरा नाम रम हो which is still not right.

Comment: @Abel: I can't use @ because I have stored the regexes in a text file . I will try with the @ . I have thousands of such replacements. Anyway thanks Abel for this. I will try.

Comment: Closers: I don'think this should be closed, as it can be considered about Unicode regular expressions that don't work the way they should. It serves a greater purpose than only the Devanagari community (which, btw, is quite large).

Comment: The @-sign should _not_ be put in your text file regexes. You should use it to use literal strings. "\w" is no proper escape in code, it should be either "\\w" or @"\w". When in a textfile, you don't have those issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I'm testing with `\w` (which, I think, should really be `\w+`) I get all kinds of results that don't seem to add up. For instance, `राम` consists of two Devanagari characters and a space. Using the expression `\w` matches the last character and the space, but using `\w{2}` does not match both characters. I don't know why.

Would it be a solution for you to use Unicode properties instead? I.e., the following works:

```
\p{IsDevanagari}+\s
```

It selects one or more consecutive Devanagari characters followed by space character. I tried with `\b` but that doesn't work. Apparently, word boundaries do not work with all Unicode scripts. Result, the following succeeds:

```
नाम (\p{IsDevanagari}+) है
```

I used this [online tester to test this](http://regexhero.net/tester/) (no, I'm not affiliated).

Comment: Don't know.. I tried with the {Devanagari} it does not seem to work or may be I must be missing something in {Devanagari}
For more info: 
I have the regexes written in 

http://code.google.com/p/nepaliwikipediatranslator/source/browse/trunk/NepaliWikiPediaTranslator/PostProcessor.cs
and the regexes in : 

http://code.google.com/p/nepaliwikipediatranslator/source/browse/trunk/NepaliWikiPediaTranslator/bin/Debug/HindiToNepali.txt

Comment: @Rajesh, use `IsDevanagari` (note the **Is**). Just `Devanagari` doesn't work, that was a typo of mine.

Comment: WOW :) 

Thanks Abel :))) 

नाम (\p{IsDevanagari}+) है
Worked perfectly :)) You're a Genius :))