# Visual Basic 2010 Replacing good substring with bad substring

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

Im using Visual Basic 2010. Im having the user enter a string, good substring, and bad substring (Three text Boxes). I need to have my code find the instances of the bad substring in my string, and replaces each instance with the good substring. I feel like there should be a loop to determine the instances of the bad substring. I just can't wrap my mind around it. Here is all I have so far. Hopefully someone can help me.

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim strEnteredString As String = txtInputString.Text.Trim
    Dim intEnteredStringChars As Integer = strEnteredString.Length
    Dim strGoodSubstring As String = txtInputGoodString.Text.Trim
    Dim intGoodSubstringChars As Integer = strGoodSubstring.Length
    Dim strBadSubstring As String = txtInputBadString.Text.Trim
    Dim intBadSubstringChars As Integer = strBadSubstring.Length


    Dim strNewString As String = strEnteredString
    Dim strNewStringFinal As String


    If strEnteredString.Contains(strBadSubstring) Then
        strNewStringFinal = strNewString.Remove(
        strNewString = strEnteredString.Insert(intBadSubstringChars, strGoodSubstring)


    End If
```

Comment: Sample data would be really helpful. You can use `String.Replace` to replace all bad with good (sub)strings. It sounds as if your question could be related to [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264262/replacing-bad-characters-of-a-string-with-bad-characters).

Comment: Just use the String.Replace() method.

Answer (score 1):

This is already built in - use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
Dim strNewStringFinal As String
strNewStringFinal = strEnteredString.Replace(strBadSubstring, strGoodSubstring)
```

Note on style - these are objects and the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is something that is not needed or encouraged, as you are simply repeating information that is already present (and is easy to find).

Comment: Yeah I forgot to comment that string.replace couldn't be used

Comment: @ron - Very strange requirement. Why not?